# Java: instance really better than static?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, static

So I have a few classes like `MainWindow`, `MenuPanel`, `GamePanel`, `GameEngine`, `Player` and so on...

My question is, although I've read much about static vs instance, which should be more recommended to use, according one of my lines looks like this:
`MainWindow.getGamePanel().getPlayer1().getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(...);`

or `MainWindow.getGamePanel().getLabels()[0].getIcon();`

Do you think this is a good practice trying so hard not to use statics where every object has different properties and things are not generalized, instead of maybe declaring the `labels` or the `players` and `names`static and having a much more easy to reuse and read code?

The idea is I used these long codes because surely it would be awkward to create a `GamePanel`*(visual class)* object in the `Player`*(more like a logical)* class for example. So I just created like one object of every class in `MainWindow` *(not the main class, just the JFrame class)* and created `static getters` for every one of them.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble telling what you're describing... it sounds like you've structured your code in a very odd way. `MainWindow.getGamePanel().getPlayer1().getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(...);` looks very suspicious to me... it looks like you're still doing everything with static references, you just have a top-level static method that returns a particular instance. It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but I bet things could be re-structured so you don't need those long access chains at all.

Comment: Lines like `MainWindow.getGamePanel().getPlayer1().getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(...);` can also be caused by poor design, not _just_ by using instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MainWindow.getGamePanel().getPlayer1().getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(...);
```

This is a classic violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), sometimes expressed as "ask, don't look."  The class calling these getters has too much knowledge of the overall structure of the program, which makes it brittle.  If the relationship between any of these classes changes, all the code that relies on these chained getters will break.

The idea behind "ask, don't look" is that the class calling these getters to get the player name should instead require the player name as a constructor parameter.  If that leads to a constructor with a huge number of parameters, the class is probably violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).